# adding List<String> friends = new ArrayList<>(); to customlistview

Tags: java, android

Cannot add List to custom list view. im having trouble with String[] , i was trying to get my users from firebase database and stores it to my
`private ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfos;`
`userInfos=new ArrayList<>();` 
but when running it to emulator my listview is showing blank,i've tried checking the `List<String> friends = new ArrayList<>();` and my users are available., Could anyone please help me with this?

My MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.java

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;



public class MainActivityCustonlistViewnew extends AppCompatActivity {



    private ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfos;
    private CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;
    private ListView customListView;



    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

    private  DatabaseReference UserData = databaseReference.child("Users");


    private List<String> friends = new ArrayList<>();

    private String[] names ;


    private String[] professions={
            "Rank 1",
            "Rank 2",
            "Rank 3"

    };
    private int[] photos={
            R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_6

    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maincustomlistview);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar));


       // ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(friends);

        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String friend = ds.getKey();

                    friends.add(friend);



                }

        }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        UserData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);




        customListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view);
        userInfos=new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(names, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        customListAdapter=new CustomListAdapter(userInfos,MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this);
        customListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
        getDatas();
        customListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this, "Name : " + names[i] + "\n Profession : " + professions[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



//sample-----












    }

    // getting all the datas
    private void getDatas(){




        for(int count=0;count<names.length;count++){

            userInfos.add(new UserInfo(names[count],professions[count],photos[count]));

        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_option,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                newText=newText.toString();
                ArrayList<UserInfo> newUserInfos=new ArrayList<>();

                for(UserInfo userInfo:userInfos){
                    String name=userInfo.getName().toLowerCase();
                    String profession=userInfo.getProfession().toLowerCase();
                    if(name.contains(newText) || profession.contains(newText)){
                        newUserInfos.add(userInfo);
                    }
                }
                customListAdapter.filterResult(newUserInfos);
                customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

my Userinfo.java

```
public class UserInfo {
    private String name,profession;
    private int photo;

    public UserInfo(){}

    public UserInfo(String name, String profession, int photo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public int getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }
}
```

my customlistAdapter

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{
    private ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfos;
    private Context context;

    public CustomListAdapter(ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfos, Context context) {
        this.userInfos = userInfos;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return userInfos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view_layout,null);
        ImageView photo,option;
        if(view==null){
            photo=new ImageView(context);
        }
        UserInfo userInfo=userInfos.get(i);
        photo=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        option=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.option);
        TextView name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView profession=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.profession);
        photo.setImageResource(userInfo.getPhoto());
        name.setText(userInfo.getName());
        profession.setText(userInfo.getProfession());
        option.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
           case R.id.option:
               showPopupMenu(view);
                break;
        }
    }

    // getting the popup menu
    private void showPopupMenu(View view){
        PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(context,view);
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_menu,popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.show();
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.edit:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Edit !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.remove:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Remove !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //file search result
    public void filterResult(ArrayList<UserInfo> newUserInfos){
        userInfos=new ArrayList<>();
        userInfos.addAll(newUserInfos);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have only get method in Userinfo.java class make set method also and you will be able to add data

Answer (score 0):

```
  customListAdapter=new CustomListAdapter(userInfos,MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this);
        customListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
        getDatas();
```

You are doing wrong here. you are calling customListAdapter and setting cusrom data(userInfos) empty here. Because  getDatas() method called after customListAdapter . Hence list will be empty. Just interchange the positron.

```
getDatas();
customListAdapter=new CustomListAdapter(userInfos,MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this);
customListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
```

Hope It helps.

Thanks
Saurabh
Happy Coding !!!

Comment: `userInfos.add()` has no problem, as `UserInfo` object is getting initialised first and added

Answer (score 0):

You're adding data from `getDatas()` but your adapter is already being initialized with empty data. So there are 2 ways :

**1 : Initialize and Set adapter after `getDatas()` call**

```
    getDatas();
    customListAdapter=new CustomListAdapter(userInfos,MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this);
    customListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
```

**2 : Inform adapter about dataset changes using `notifyDataSetChanged()` method**

```
    customListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
    getDatas();
    customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```